# AS3: Create sprites from loaded image

Tags: actionscript-3

I don't know if the title is misleading as the image I'm loading is actually a sprite image consisting of a multi-state button. I want to load this image and split it into several display objects (sprites?) in AS3, to create a `SimpleButton` with an over and down state.

Right now I'm just loading the image with `Loader` and `URLRequest`, and then creating a sprite from the loaded content.

Is this possible or is there any other way of doing this, without having to load two separate images?

Thanks in advance,
Pierre

Comment: as @SynerCode mentioned, you can use a mask. It might also be worth looking at the scrollRect property(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect)

Comment: Thank you @George Profenza, this is the solution I chose to use :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is. You can use the [mask function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) of the Sprite class. First you set the mask to normalstate button part of the image,, and on mouseover you set the mask to the other state and on mouse down you set the mask to the clickstate button part of the image

---

Please mark as answer if this helped.